# How can I start developing npm packages for react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm

1. What languages should I know before developing packages for react-native that support both android and ios ?
2. Please refer me some docs or blogs which could be useful for developing npm packages for react-native that support both android and ios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To develop packages which support both android and ios you should be
   familier with native development for android(java and kotlin) and
   for ios(objective C and Swift). Also you should be sound in
   JavaScript, React and React Native and Package Managers (npm/yarn).
2. Some resources:

- [React Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started)
- [React Native docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/)
- [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/)
- [JavaScript Mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Comment: Thank u . is it possible with java and c alone or a compulsion to know kotlin and swift ? @ujjawal-kumar

Comment: @abhisheksharma go with the industry trend there's no specific answer's ralated to the tech stack

Answer (score 0):

You can also checkout [Expo Modules API](https://docs.expo.dev/modules/overview/). They developed a really easy way of writing react native libraries and its probably a good start point for building your first.